# creating table with reactjs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to create a table using reactjs. I wrote a class and using this as directive, passing config and data and trying to populate the table.

```
function createRows() {
    let self = this;
    return  <tbody>{_.each(self.props.tableData, function(r) {
        <tr>
            {_.each(self.props.columnConfigs, function(c) {
            <td>{r[c.columnName]}</td>
        })}
        </tr>
    })}</tbody>;
}

function createHeaders() {

    let self = this;
    return <thead>
    {_.each(self.props.columnConfigs, function(c) {
            <th>c.displayName</th>
        })}
    </thead>
}
class TableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {

       return (<table>
            {createHeaders.call(this)}
            {createRows.call(this)}
        </table>)
    }


}

function TableComponentFactory() {
    return TableComponent;
}

export default TableComponentFactory;
```

But this is not working. it throws an error:-

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {columnName, displayName, isSortable, path, hidden, columnStyle, editable, isId}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `TableComponent`.
```

which is actually the columnConfig. I am not able to understand why this happening. What mistake I am doing, also a bit of explanation will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 'each' (from which function no return value is expected), you should use 'map' and use 'return (<JSX Element>)' in its body. Each should be use to apply an action on every item in an array without returning data. But you want to return data, because you want the function to supply rows and columns.